# "hidden" vs #keyPath(UIView.isHidden)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, key-value-observing

**KVO** observer with `#keyPath(UIView.isHidden)` does not work, but `"hidden"` works.

Very strange. Is it bug or feature?

```
child.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "hidden", options: [.initial,.new], context: nil);

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, .change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if let view = object as? UIView, view.superview === self && keyPath == "hidden" {
        print("*");
    }
}
```

Comment: Could it be related to the fact that it's declared like this (in Objective-C): `@property(nonatomic, getter=isHidden) BOOL hidden;`, `isHidden` being only the getter and not the property "name/path"?

Comment: Autocomplete for #keyPath(UIView.___) suggests to insert  "isHidden", not "hidden".

Comment: Seems like a bug. On Xcode 12, `#keyPath(UIView.isHidden)` is now correctly interpreted as "hidden".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Is it bug or feature?

Let's say it's a known fact. "Renamification" means that Swift pretends that the name of an Objective-C Bool property starts with `is...` even when it doesn't. But the `#keyPath` mechanism didn't get the memo when it comes to KVO and property setter names, and property setter swizzling to implement KVO observing is purely an Objective-C feature, so you have to use the *real* name of the property / setter, i.e. the Objective-C name, so that communication with Objective-C works correctly for KVO observation purposes.

I've filed a bug report on it (https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2415) on the grounds that Swift could behave a little smarter about this, but until the Swift gang respond, it's just something you have know and deal with.

Comment: Please feel free to pile onto my bug report.