# RxSwift - make one UI element hidden/not hidden according to other element

Tags: swift, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

Im using `RxSwift` and `RxCocoa` in my project.

I have some `UITextField` named "lastNameTF", and there is a `UILabel` name "lastNameTitle".

I wanna know if there is any way to set the `isHidden` value of lastNameTitle always be equal to `isHidden` value of lastNameTF using `RxSwift`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can use KVO as described here -
https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/Documentation/GettingStarted.md#kvo

Answer (score 1):

It is super easy to use KVO.  [Here is an example](https://github.com/popmedic/swift-TextFieldKVO) of exactly what you are trying to do, just without using RxSwift (don't know what that is...)

Here is the gist of it

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private var lastNameTextFieldHiddenContext = 0
    private var lastNameObservingView:UIView? = nil
    @IBOutlet weak var lastNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lastNameTextField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // add the observer
        lastNameTextField.addObserver(
            self,
            forKeyPath: "hidden",
            options: [.new],
            context: &self.lastNameTextFieldHiddenContext
        )
    }

    /// function will be called whenever an added observer is triggered
    override func observeValue(
        forKeyPath keyPath: String?,
        of object: Any?,
        change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?,
        context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?
    ) {
        // make sure it is our text field isHidden observer
        if context == &self.lastNameTextFieldHiddenContext {
            // get the new value that was set
            if let newValue = change?[NSKeyValueChangeKey.newKey] as? Bool {
                // do what needs to be done when the observer is triggered
                self.lastNameLabel.isHidden = newValue
            }
        }
    }

    deinit {
        // remove the observer
        if let view = self.lastNameObservingView {
            view.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "hidden")
            self.lastNameObservingView = nil
        }
    }

    @IBAction func showHideButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
        self.lastNameTextField.isHidden = !self.lastNameTextField.isHidden
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is not exactly what i looked for, but it helped me in some way.
RxSwift is awesome you should check it out.
My problem was that i tried to listen to property with "keyPath" named "isHidden", but after reading your answer i saw that u used "hidden" as keyPath and it worked for me :)

Comment: This explains why it is "hidden" not "isHidden".  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41746751/hidden-vs-keypathuiview-ishidden

Answer (score 0):

If you still need a simple RxSwift approach please try this:

```
// Controls are visible by default (isHidden = false)
let isControlHidden = BehaviorRelay<Bool>(value: false)

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  let isHiddenDriver = self.isControlHidden.asDriver()

  isHiddenDriver
    .drive(self.lastNameTitle.rx.isHidden)
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)

  isHiddenDriver
    .drive(self.lastNameTF.rx.isHidden)
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

Since you need both control visibilities bound to each other, you can use a Subject or Relay to achieve that, in this case isControlHidden. So, if you want to show/hide the, you just emit a new signal:

```
@IBAction func hide(_ sender: Any) {
  self.isControlHidden.accept(true)
}

@IBAction func show(_ sender: Any) {
  self.isControlHidden.accept(false)
}
```

Comment: It looks great but there is compile error - Value of type 'Binder<Bool>' has no member 'asDriver'

Comment: You are right. 'lastNameTF.rx.isHidden' is not a ControlProperty but a Binder. However, I updated my answer with a still clean feasible solution that might help you.